# Ti SensorTag App Development

Tags: java, android, git

quite new to Java and Android development as a whole, I only have knowledge with C/C++ and Matlab.

I'm trying to run the Ti SensorTag app. The source code is given on https://git.ti.com/sensortag-android/sensortag-android/trees/master

The app crashes when I try to run it on my emulator, I've tried 4.4.2, 4.4.3, and 5.

However, in the AndroidManifest.xml, it refers to a ServiceActivity source file that simply does not exist. I have another version that is tweaked slightly (data is calculated differently) that should supposedly work as well but does not either. Not sure if that is the thing causing the problem. Could anyone else try and get this app running on their emulator?

I will post the logcat file and if you guys need to see any of the actual code, let me know.

```
06-30 19:29:49.477    6230-6230/com.example.ti.ble.sensortag D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
06-30 19:29:49.537    6230-6230/com.example.ti.ble.sensortag D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 63K, 4% free 3178K/3300K, paused 2ms, total 7ms
06-30 19:29:49.537    6230-6230/com.example.ti.ble.sensortag I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 4.232MB for 1127532-byte allocation
06-30 19:29:49.557    6230-6236/com.example.ti.ble.sensortag D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 4278K/4404K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
06-30 19:29:49.617    6230-6230/com.example.ti.ble.sensortag E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
06-30 19:29:49.647    6230-6230/com.example.ti.ble.sensortag D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 83K, 4% free 4433K/4576K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
06-30 19:29:49.677    6230-6230/com.example.ti.ble.sensortag D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-30 19:29:49.677    6230-6230/com.example.ti.ble.sensortag W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0d06b20)
06-30 19:29:49.677    6230-6230/com.example.ti.ble.sensortag E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ti.ble.sensortag, PID: 6230
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.ti.ble.sensortag.MainActivity.updateGuiState(MainActivity.java:411)
            at com.example.ti.ble.sensortag.MainActivity.onScanViewReady(MainActivity.java:277)
            at com.example.ti.ble.sensortag.ScanView.onCreateView(ScanView.java:119)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:478)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Very much would appreciate any feedback, thanks!

Comment: It looks like it crashes if BLE is not supported. Also, what kind of emulator are you running that supports Bluetooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SensorTag application can't run on emulators because they don't have bluetooth support.
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#limitations

Comment: Wow. Appreciate the quick response. Didn't think the app if it didn't support it though...

Any idea as to why it requests for a source file called "ServiceActivity"? It seems to make the .apk just fine even though it doesn't come with this file in the git link.

Comment: ServiceActivity is never called from anywhere. So we can ignore the existence of it on AndroidManifest.xml. It might be a trace of past code. Registering a service on AndroidManifest doesn't mean that it requests for a source.